# Xubuntu 18.04 LTS does not recognize executables

Tags: xubuntu, executable

I upgraded to Xubuntu 18.04, and I have a problem with executable files because it recognizes (application/x-sharedlib) instead of (application/x-executable).
How can I resolve this problem?.
Thanks

[image: screenshot]

Comment: In order to get useful answers you'll need to add more details: What did you try, what do you expect, and what exactly failed. Add screenshots or commands you use, and also a listing (`ls -l`) of the files in question. See also [ask].

Comment: Thanks for your reply;
This is a screenshot, of what I explain. It is an executable generated with two different systems Xubuntu 16.04 and Xubuntu 18.04.The exe works fine but the Xubuntu 18.04 system recognizes it as a shared library file.
Thanks